# Speech to speech recognition android studio

Tags: java, android

Apologise if this question is structured wrong or in the wrong place.

I was wondering if it was possible to speech to speech recongition in android studio on an app?

For example the user says logout and the application responds by saying goodbye and logs them out?

Is this possible or just text to speech possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible. you need to use some API to convert the audio to text, you can use google speech-to-text API (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text), there may be others, but I just know this one.

Then depending on the text that you get from the API you need to do your own logic, like for example, if you get the work "logout" you then use text to speach to say "goodbye" and then you logout the user.

Comment: Would this work in the example, if the user verbally said 'logout?' Rather than clicking a button I was thinking of an app that is majority voice controlled.

Comment: no, they do not need to click on logout button, but you need to know when to send the audio to the API so it can process it. You can do something like alexa where you say a wake up word then all the audio that captures it will send to the API, or you could have a button that starts record the audio while pressed and then send to the API

Comment: glad I could help, you still should look it up more to see your possibilities. If you can do that without an activation word or button press to start record